# How to calculate the basis of the sum of two subspaces

Tags: linear-algebra, bilinear-form

I have the following vectorial subspaces :

U = $\left(\begin{pmatrix} 2 \\ 0 \\ 1 \\ -2 \end{pmatrix},\begin{pmatrix} 3 \\ 6 \\ 9 \\ -12 \end{pmatrix} \right)$ and V = $\left(\begin{pmatrix} 0 \\ 2 \\ 1 \\ 0 \end{pmatrix},\begin{pmatrix} -1 \\ 1 \\ 0 \\ 1 \end{pmatrix} \right)$

To calculate the basis of U + V should have use this method :
$$ U + V = \left(\begin{pmatrix} (2+0) \\ (0+2) \\ (1+1) \\ (-2+0) \end{pmatrix} , \begin{pmatrix} (3-1) \\ (6+1) \\ (9+0) \\ (-12+1)\end{pmatrix} \right)$$ and use the Gaussian elimination to calculate 
$$\left(\begin{array}{cc|c} 2 & 2 & x_1 \\ 2 & 7 & x_2 \\ 2 & 9 & x_3 \\ -2 & -11 & x_4 \end{array}\right)
$$

Or I am wrong and it's $\left(\begin{array}{cccc|c} 2 & 3 &0 & -1& 0 \\ 0 & 6 &2&1 & 0 \\ 1 & 9 &1&0&0 \\ -2 & -12&0&1 & 0 \end{array}\right)$ which generate this solution after reduction $\left(\begin{array}{cccc|c} 1 & 0 &0 & -\frac{1}{2}& 0 \\ 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 1 & \frac{1}{2} & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \end{array}\right)$ $\sim$ $\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 & 0 & -\frac{1}{2} \\ 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 1 & \frac{1}{2} \end{pmatrix}$

Thank you for your responses!

Comment: Yo mean $U = \operatorname{span}\left\{\begin{pmatrix} 2 \\ 0 \\ 1 \\ -2 \end{pmatrix},\begin{pmatrix} 3 \\ 6 \\ 9 \\ -12 \end{pmatrix} \right\}$?

Comment: @Azif00 I forget to write span

Answer (score 2):

The former is wrong. To illustrate why, consider a simpler example:
$$U = \operatorname{span}((1, 0)) \quad V = \operatorname{span}((0, 1)).$$
Then $U + V = \Bbb{R}^2$, as any point $(a, b) \in \Bbb{R}^2$ can be expressed as
$$(a, b) = (a, 0) + (0, b)$$
where $(a, 0) = a(1, 0) \in U$ and $(0, b) = b(0, 1) \in V$. However, using your method, we get
$$U + V \stackrel{?}{=} \operatorname{span}((1, 0) + (0, 1)) = \operatorname{span}((1,1)),$$
which is clearly false, as $\operatorname{span}((1,1))$ is the line $y = x$, not all of $\Bbb{R}^2$.

Note also that this method of adding subspaces is sensitive to choice of basis. We could just as easily write $V = \operatorname{span}((0, 2))$, but $\operatorname{span}((1, 0) + (0, 2)) \neq \operatorname{span}((1, 0) + (0, 1))$. This is another hint that this method is not sound.

On the other hand, the latter method is sound. In general, if $B_1$ and $B_2$ are sets of vectors, then
$$\operatorname{span} B_1 + \operatorname{span} B_2 = \operatorname{span}(B_1 \cup B_2).$$
This follows immediately from working with linear combinations; a linear combination of $B_1$ plus a linear combination of $B_2$ is always a linear combination of $B_1 \cup B_2$. Conversely, one can take a linear combination of $B_1 \cup B_2$, separate out the terms, and write it as a linear combination of $B_1$ plus a linear combination of $B_2$.

So, if you wish to find a basis for $U + V$, union their bases (for a set of four vectors), then row reduce to find a basis for the span. The resulting basis is a basis for $U + V$.

Comment: once I calculate the sum, to find the cartesian equation(s), do i just have to replace the zeros after the reduction with $x,y,z,t$?

Comment: @Moh18 I don't understand what you're asking. Once you form $A$, the matrix formed by putting the $4$ vectors as columns, row reduce to $A'$. Note that $A'$ has pivots in the first three columns, so the first three columns of $A$ form a basis for $U + V$.

Comment: I have to find after that the cartesian equation(s) of U + V and I don't know how to do so in this situation (sorry if it's a stupid question).

Comment: @Moh18 Oh, I see. If you want a cartesian equation for this hyperplane in $\Bbb{R}^4$, then you need to find a normal vector. There are a few ways to do this. Probably the most conceptually simple is to let $(a, b, c, d)$ be a vector that dot products with each basis vector to produce $0$. Doing so will produce a system of three equations in $a, b, c, d$, corresponding to putting the basis vectors as **rows** into a matrix. Solve this system to get one free variable, and choose a non-zero solution. This will be a normal vector, and your cartesian equation will be $ax+by+cz+dt=0$.

Comment: @Moh18 If you want more help than this for the next step, ask a new question, let me know, and I'll be happy to help.

Comment: so I have to reduce $\left(\begin{array}{cccc|c} 2 & 3 &0 & -1& a \\ 0 & 6 &2&1 & b \\ 1 & 9 &1&0&c \\ -2 & -12&0&1 & d \end{array}\right)$?

Comment: @Moh18 No, the equations are $(2, 0, 1, -2) \cdot (a, b, c, d) = 0$, $(3, 6, 9, -12) \cdot (a, b, c, d) = 0$, etc. The augmented column will be $0$, and $a, b, c, d$ are the variables. If you expand out these four equations, and form a matrix, you'll find that the basis vectors are **rows**, not columns.

Comment: If I understand correctly, with the augmented matrix we know that U+V is a linear combination of the first three columns of $\left(\begin{array}{cccc|c} 2 & 3 &0 & -1& 0 \\ 0 & 6 &2&1 & 0 \\ 1 & 9 &1&0&0 \\ -2 & -12&0&1 & 0 \end{array}\right)$ then I have to reduce $$\left(\begin{array}{ccc|c} 2 & 3 &0 & x_1 \\ 0 & 6 &2 & x_2 \\ 1 & 9 &1&x_3 \\ -2 & -12&0 & x_4 \end{array}\right)$$ to find the cartesian equation(s)

Comment: @Moh18 Right, I see what you're doing. Yes, this will work. Row reduce this down to row-echelon form, and whatever condition on $(x_1, x_2, x_3, x_4)$ is necessary for the system to be consistent will be the cartesian equation.